# How to restrict an instance variable value not to go beyond the limits defined

Tags: python, oop

The below code results in negative balance. Instead of putting an if condition in withdrawl method, I am looking for some other way to have a check and restrict when balance becomes negative.

```
class Customer(object):

    def __init__(self, balance):
        self.balance = balance

    def withdrawl(self, amount):
        self.balance -= amount
        return self.balance

jeff = Customer(1000.0)
print jeff.withdrawl(2000)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am looking for a way other than adding conditions. I dont know the scope of python in achieving the same.

Comment: And the rationale for avoiding the use of a keyword would be?

Comment: `self.balance -= amount * (self.balance >= amount)`

Comment: Wants to know, if this is in the scope or not. Dont know how to search for the same in tutorials. Using the keyword resolves, which I know.

Comment: As  falsetru demostrates, you don't _need_ to use an `if` statement. Another option would be to use a custom object to store the value which can never be negative, but the code for that object would need to use an `if` statement or syntax like that in falsetru's example. OTOH, the Zen of Python says: "Explicit is better than implicit". And surely you don't want to silently limit the balance to zero if an attempt is made to withdraw more than the current balance. Don't you also want to generate some kind of warning or error message?

Comment: Thanks PM 2Ring. I am not concerned about the messages as this question is put just to know the possibility in python. Can you please guide me in how to make a custom object in python to achieve the requirement.

Comment: @S.Sreeram I didn't ask what you want to know, but what the **rationale** for want you want to do would be.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
class Balance():

    def __init__(self,x):
        assert x >= 0, "Balance can't be negative!"
        self.value = x

class Customer(object):

    def __init__(self, balance):
        self.balance = balance

    def withdrawl(self, amount):
        self.balance = Balance(self.balance.value - amount)
        return self.balance

jeff = Customer(Balance(1000.0))
print jeff.withdrawl(2000)
```

But it seems like an overkill to me. Why not use an if statement?